# Qt C++, очередность сигналов-слотов

Tags: c++, qt

Ситуация следующая:

1. Есть MainWindow.cpp и test.cpp
2. В MainWindow стоит связка сигнал-слот 
   `connect(test, SIGNAL(SendLog(QString, QString)), this, SLOT(setLogs(QString, QString)));`
3. В test.cpp есть класс work который отправляет ПОСТ запрос и по результату совершает:
   `emit SendLog("1", "222");`
4. MainWindow есть QTextBrowser, в который setLogs вставляет данные.

Далее в MainWindow, делаю следующее:

```
test *testDo = new test ();
setLogs ("0", "111");
testDo->work ();
setLogs ("0", "333");
```

Все отрабатывает нормально, ПОСТ выполняется, но в QTextBrowser выводится

```
111

333

222
```

Хотя по логике должно идти по порядку.

Подскажите, в чем может быть загвоздка и как правильно реализовать логирование сообщений

Comment: В `testDo->work()` у вас в отдельном потоке вызывается `emit SendLog("1", "222");` ?

Comment: И про "`ПОСТ запрос`" можно поподробнее, что это. Если он выполняется асинхронно, то вывод лога вполне логичен.

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что `manager` это объект типа `QNetworkAccessManager`. Его метод `post` выполняется асинхронно. Т.е. управление возвращается сразу, а когда будет возможно прочитать результат, сработает сигнал `readyRead`, в котором вы вызываете свой сигнал `SendLog`.

Т.е. порядок вывода логов вполне корректный:

```
test *testDo = new test ();
setLogs ("0", "111");   // здесь полчаем в лог 111
testDo->work ();        // здесь ничего пока не получаем, т.к. ответ ещё не получен от сервера.
setLogs ("0", "333");   // здесь получаем в лог 333
                        // здесь получаем в лог 222, как только придет ответ от сервера.
```

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда вопрос: а как выполнить запрос не асинхронно?

Comment: @user4150916 лучше отдельным вопросом оформить

Answer (score -1):

Дело в том, что в Qt есть правила обработки сигналов. В Вашем случае для прямого вызова слота во время выхлоп сигнала,  необходимо использовать Qt::DirectConnection.

```
  connect(test, SIGNAL(SendLog(QString, QString)), this, SLOT(setLogs(QString, QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```